# User needs to be granted the Release Manager role to update the existing database

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, azure-devops, release-management, ms-release-management

I moved an existing RM database over to a new environment and installed RM. However, when configuring, I get the error, "The User ____ needs to be granted the Release Manager role to update the existing database for Release Management."

I had uninstalled the RM client and server to upgrade to 2013.4, so I don't have access to the client to add it to the RM role. Is there any other way to add the user as a release manager in SQL Server? I've tried adding it as a dbo but that doesn't work. I know that I can open RM server with the existing RM database's previous dbo, but I'd prefer to solve this another way. Or is that the only way?

Comment: I think adding `db_owner` role for the user will fix it, if you have no problem with giving this role to the user

Comment: Nope, unfortunately, doesn't solve it :(

Answer (score 2):

Uninstall the server component (will leave the database intact) and then re-run the installation of the server either logged in to the machine as User__ or do a Run As on the installation exe as User__.

Answer (score 2):

I solved this problem by deleting the `ReleaseManagement` Database in the server and re-running the wizard once again. Found the solution in this [link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/972c9314-237d-4c9e-92e8-7c58b46460bc/issues-installing-release-management-server?forum=tfsbuild)

Comment: its solved my problem, i just deleted existing release management Database, so i install release management successfully but only problem is how can we use our existing database, it was already configured. but new is fresh DB.

Comment: @adnan Sorry my application was a prototype . so it didnt matter if we deleted the databse. I wont be able to help

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to make uninstall at all, you can connect to Microsoft SQL Server on with you have Release Management database running using SQL Server Management Studio and run some query's that will check if you have this user 'User ____'

Check

```
USE [ReleaseManagement]
    GO
SELECT *
  FROM [ReleaseManagement].[dbo].[User] WHERE UserName = 'User ____ '
```

If you have already this user in this table take the id if not make insert to this table and get the id that was created.

Later check the table

```
USE [ReleaseManagement]
GO

SELECT [PartitionId]
      ,[UserId]
      ,[UserRoleId]
  FROM [ReleaseManagement].[dbo].[User_UserRole]
  Where UserId = [IdOfUser 'User ____ ']
```

If not exist make insert

```
USE [ReleaseManagement]
GO

INSERT INTO [dbo].[User_UserRole]
           ([PartitionId]
           ,[UserId]
           ,[UserRoleId])
     VALUES
           (1,[IdOfUser],1)

GO
```